# Backward induction: equation including expected values of stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, monte-carlo, stochastic-integral, transition-distribution

Given the following SDE: $$ d\psi_t = \rho dt + \mu \psi_t dX_t$$, where $G(t) = \rho t$, $\rho = \frac{1}{T}$ $\psi_0 =0$, $T=1$, $\mu > 0$ and $X_t$ is a standard Brownian Motion (assume we know one specific path of $\psi_t$). Further, $E$ denote the mathematical expectation and $1$ the indicator function.

The goal is to find some function $a(t)$ that can be obtained by solving an equation by backward induction using a partition $0\leq t_0 < t_1 \dots < t_n = T$ of $[0, T]$ given the 'starting' value $a(t_n) = a(T) = 0$.

If we now define the mesh by $\Delta = t_n - t_{n-1}$ the above mentioned equation is in the following form:

---

- First step of backward induction: $\quad t = t_{n-1}$

$$ E_{a(t_{n-1})} \left[ 1_{ \\\{ \psi_{\Delta} < a(t_n) \\\} } \psi_{\Delta}  \right] = 0 \quad \implies \quad E_{a(t_{n-1})} \left[ 1_{ \\\{ \psi_{\Delta} < 0 \\\} } \psi_{\Delta}  \right] = 0 $$

This equation should be solvable using Monte-Carlo to simulate values for $\psi_{\Delta}$ with $\psi_0 = a(t_{n-1})$, compute the average of $\left( 1_{ \\\{ \psi_{i} < 0 \\\} } \psi_{i} \right)$ and solve for $a(t_{n-1})$. (How?)

As an alternative it should be possible to derive an explicit formula for the transitional density of $\psi$ and also being able to solve for $a(t_{n-1})$. (Again: How?)

---

- Second step, as we know $a(t_{n-1})$: $\quad t = t_{n-2}$

\begin{align}
& E_{a(t_{n-2})} \left[ 1_{ \\\{ \psi_{2\Delta} < 0 \\\} } \psi_{2\Delta}  \right] \\\\ + & E_{a(t_{n-2})} \left[ 1_{ \\\{ \psi_{\Delta} < a(t_{n-1}) \\\} } \right] + E_{a(t_{n-2})} \left[ 1_{ \\\{ \psi_{\Delta} < a(t_{n-1}) \\\} } \psi_{\Delta}  \right] = 0
\end{align}

By solving this again we are supposed to get the value for $a(t_{n-2})$ and we continue expanding the equation to get values for $a(t_{n-3}), \dots, a(t_0)$, e.g.:

---

- Third step, as we know $a(t_{n-2})$: $\quad t = t_{n-3}$

\begin{align}
& E_{a(t_{n-3})} \left[ 1_{ \\\{ \psi_{3\Delta} < 0 \\\} } \psi_{3\Delta}  \right] + \\\\ & E_{a(t_{n-3})} \left[ 1_{ \\\{ \psi_{2\Delta} < a(t_{n-1}) \\\} } \right] + E_{a(t_{n-3})} \left[ 1_{ \\\{ \psi_{2\Delta} < a(t_{n-1}) \\\} } \psi_{\Delta}  \right] + \\\\ & E_{a(t_{n-3})} \left[ 1_{ \\\{ \psi_{\Delta} < a(t_{n-2}) \\\} } \right] + E_{a(t_{n-3})} \left[ 1_{ \\\{ \psi_{\Delta} < a(t_{n-2}) \\\} } \psi_{\Delta}  \right] = 0
\end{align}

---

I struggle in how to derive the correct values $a(t)$ for every point of the partition as I don't know how to solve the expanding equation (neither for $t = t_{n-1}$ nor for even smaller values of $t$ as the equation doesn't get handier). There were signs that point towards Monte-Carlo and/or transitional density of $\psi$ but yet I failed to figure out how to apply either method. Maybe anyone can point out?